# Posting leaked data

Tags: hacking

Is it legal to publicly share leaked data (for example, twitter.com user emails, names, and passwords)?

Comment: It really depends how you got it and whether you're subject to any agreements not to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It is legal to save and index a copy of any leaked database?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/it-is-legal-to-save-and-index-a-copy-of-any-leaked-database)

Comment: @david assume no agreements (the hypothetical doesn't assert any) and your answer can explain how the manner in which one receives the leaked data affects the result.

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy. There's a list of criminal charges that could be in someone's way if that happened. Assuming Canadian law, there are a couple offences coming to mind:

- *Unauthorized use of a computer*. §342.1 of the [Criminal Code of Canada](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/):

  > Everyone is guilty of an indictable offence and liable to imprisonment for a term of not more than 10 years, or is guilty of an offence punishable on summary conviction who, fraudulently and without colour of right,
  >
  > > (d) uses, possesses, traffics in or permits another person to have access to a computer password that would enable a person to commit an offence under paragraph (a), (b) or (c).
- *Mischief in relation to computer data*. §430(1.1) of the [Criminal Code of Canada](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/):

  > Every one commits mischief who wilfully
  >
  > > (c) obstructs, interrupts or interferes with the lawful use of data;